# Pyspark Linear Regression Gradient Descent CrossValidation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am attempting to perform cross validation on a SGD model in pyspark, I am working with `LinearRegressionWithSGD` from `pyspark.mllib.regression` , `ParamGridBuilder` and `CrossValidator` both from the `pyspark.ml.tuning` libraries.

After following [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-tuning.html) from the Spark website, I was *hoping* running this would work

```
lr = LinearRegressionWithSGD()
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[lr])

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
    .addGrid(lr.stepSize, Array(0.1, 0.01))\
    .build()

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,estimatorParamMaps= paramGrid,
                         evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(),
                         numFolds=10)
```

But `LinearRegressionWithSGD()` does not have the attributes `stepSize` (tried others with no luck either).

I can set lr to `LinearRegression` but then I am unable to use SGD for my model and cross validate.

There is the `kFold` method within [scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/util/MLUtils.html#MLUtils()) but I am not sure how to access that from pyspark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the step parameter from [LinearRegressionWithSGD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD) to define your step size but that will not allow your code to work because you are mixing incompatible libraries.  Unfortunately, I do not know how to do cross validation with the ml library using SGD optimization and I would like to know myself but you are mixing the libraries [pyspark.ml](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#) and [pyspark.mllib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/mllib-guide.html). Specifically you cannot use [LinearRegressionWithSGD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD) with the pyspark.ml library.  You have to use [pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression).

The good news is you can set the set the solver attribute of [pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression) to use 'gd'.  Therefore, you can probably set the parameters of the 'gd' optimizer run as SGD, but I am not sure where the solver documentation is or how to set the solver attributes (e.g. the batch size).  The [api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression) shows the LinearRegression object calling Param() but I am not sure if it is using the pyspark.mllib optimizer.  If anyone knows how to set the solver attributes, that could answer your question by allowing you to use the Pipeline, ParamGridBuilder, and CrossValidation ml packages for model selection with LinearRegression utilizing SGD optimization for parameter tuning.

Respectfully,
Shane